# how to capture from group from end line in js regex?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to capture a text into 3 groups I have managed to capture 2 groups but having an issue with the 3rd group.

This is the text :

> <13>Apr  5 16:09:47 node2 Services: 2016-04-05 16:09:46,914 INFO  [3]
>   Drivers.KafkaInvoker - KafkaInvoker.SendMessages - After sending
>   itemsCount=1

I'm using the following regex:

```
(?=- )(.*?)(?= - )|(?=])(.*?)(?= -)
```

My 3rd group should be : "After sending itemsCount=1"

any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean like this? `^.*?\[\d+\]([^-]+)-([^-]+)-([^-]+)$` [demo](https://regex101.com/r/gdfoie/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your original expression is fine, just missing a `$`:

```
(?=- )(.*?)(?= - |$)|(?=])(.*?)(?= -)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IwcxIX/1/)

and maybe we would slightly modify that to an expression similar to:

```
(?=-\s+).*?([A-Z].*?)(?=\s+-\s+|$)|(?=]\s+).*?([A-Z].*?)(?=\s+-)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gBJE5q/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 capturing groups. You don't get the match for the third part because the postitive lookahead in the first alternation is not considering the end of the string. You might solve that by using an alternation to look at either a space or assert the end of the string

```
(?=[-\]] )(.*?)(?= - |$)
                     ^^
```

If those matches are ok, you could simplify that pattern by making use of a character class to match either `-` or `]` like `[-\]]` and omit the alternation and the group as you now have only the matches.

Your pattern then might look like (also capturing the leading hyphen like the first 2 matches)

```
(?=[-\]] ).*?(?= - |$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wFDMsB/1)

If this is your string and you want to have 3 capturing groups, you might use:

```
^.*?\[\d+\]([^-]+)-([^-]+)-\s*([^-]+)$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `.*?` Match any char except a newline non greedy
- `\[\d+\]` match `[` 1+ digits `]`
- `([^-]+)-` Capture group 1, match 1+ times not `-`, then match `-`
- `([^-]+)-` Capture group 2, match 1+ times not `-`, then match `-`
- `\s*` Match 0+ whitespace chars
- `([^-]+)` Capture group 2, match 1+ times not `-`
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/psx0xa/1)

For example creating the desired object from the comments, you could first get all the matches from `match[0]` and store those in an array.

After you have have all the values, assemble the object using the keys and the values.

```js
var output = {};
var regex = new RegExp(/(?=[-\]] ).*?(?= - |$)/g);
var str = `<13>Apr 5 16:09:47 node2 Services: 2016-04-05 16:09:46,914 INFO [3] Drivers.KafkaInvoker - KafkaInvoker.SendMessages - After sending itemsCount=1`;
var match;
var values = [];
var keys = ['Thread', 'Class', 'Message'];

while ((match = regex.exec(str)) !== null) {
  // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
  if (match.index === regex.lastIndex) {
    regex.lastIndex++;
  }
  values.push(match[0]);
}
keys.forEach((key, index) => output[key] = values[index]);
console.log(output);
```

Comment: thanks! it works just that when I implement the regex to my script it returns with "undefined" , do you know why? 

var output = {};
var regex = new RegExp(/(?=[-\]] ).*?(?= - |$)/g);
var match = regex.exec("<13>Apr  5 16:09:47 node2 Services: 2016-04-05 16:09:47,820 INFO  [4] rs.RawDataSaveModule - LoadAffiliateOfferData() - found a valid association for aff_id=2000013342, offer_id=30933, tenantId=1");
if (match !== null && match.length > 0) {
 output['Thread'] = match[1]
 output['Class'] = match[2]
 output['Message'] = match[3]
}
console.log(output);

Comment: @DrorYelin I have updated the question with an example. You could use exec in a while loop. Note that you don't have 3 groups but just a single match. You could first store all the matches in an array and then create the object from it.